# ArcGIS API for Javascript nd BING tiles

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, bing-maps

I'm using the "esri.virtualearth.VETiledLayer" in my map application as a basemap successfull,y but am restricted to 18 levels of detail.  BING's resultion is higher than this, but the ESRI widget seems restricted to only show to a certain level.  Is there a way around this?  I already tried setting LODs on the map object, but the map goes blank past level 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out.  For anyone who finds this:

Downloaded the esri/virtualearth/VETiledLayer widget here:
http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/virtualearth/VETiledLayer.js

Then modified with another level of detail:

```
 { level: 20, resolution: 0.1492910708238085, scale: 564.248588 }
```

Then referenced modified version in my app.